# How load a ListBox from code behind when DataContext is set to a modelview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I set DataContext of window to a viewmodel but in XAML I want to bind a listbox to bind to `People` object in code behind file. Is it possible to do that?

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();

        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        People.Add(new Person() { Name = "Mark", Age = 20 });
        People.Add(new Person() { Name = "John", Age = 25 });

        DataContext = vm;
    }
```

XAML

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

My dilemma is that I want `People`to be loaded from code behind but I want to have the `SelectedPerson` in viewmodel.

Now I know I can declare my MainViewModel as a property and set DataContext in code behind to `this` and then my XAML would be like below:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding vm.SelectedPerson}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

But I really want to set `DataContext` to my viewmodel because all of XAML (in real app) binds to viewmodel and I only want one listbox to load from code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `People` is a property of the MainWindow class:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding People, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

---

Or just directly assign the ItemsSource property in code behind:

```
listbox1.ItemsSource = People;
```

Comment: Following up from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=netcore-3.1) "However, the RelativeSource property is one of the ways you can explicitly set the source of a Binding and override the inherited data context". So this is not relative to DataContext but completely discards that? It's relative to the control itself?

Comment: It does not "discard it", but has higher precedence and hence "overrides" it. The DataContext of a FrameworkElement establishes a default source object for any Binding of a dependency property of the element, which is used when the source is not explicitly set, by either Source, RelativeSource or ElementName. The exact behavior of RelativeSource is determined by its [Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.mode?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: But is it fair to say it replaces it for the listbox? Override is a bit of soft word but generally it essentially means replacing as well unless there is is something else to it.

Comment: If you set RelativeSource, the current DataContext is ignored / ineffective / irrelevant - call it however you like. The former just has higher precedence, as it explicitly sets the source object.